# AES encryption in php and then decryption with Javascript (cryptojs)

Tags: php, javascript, encryption, mcrypt, cryptojs

I'm searching for a way to make a 2 way encryption of a simple text (5 to 6 numbers and/or characters). The catch is that i want to make the encryption in php and then decrypt it via Javascript. For php i've tested using mcrypt_encode and have gotten it to work, hence when i try to decrypt it with javascript (i'm using the Crypto-js library - http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ ) i get no results. Here is the php code i'm using:

```
$key = "oijhd981727783hy18274";
$text = "1233";
$td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);
echo base64_encode($crypttext);
```

and then here is the Javascript code i'm using:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("LiJU5oYHXRSNsrjMtCr5o2ev7yDFGZId85gh9MEXPeg=");
var key = 'oijhd981727783hy18274';
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
document.write( decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8) );
```

As i'm just testing, i copy/paste the output from the php straight into the JS and see if it would return any results, however that doesnt happen. As i'm new to the encryption/decryption part i might be missing something. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

On a side note, as i read a lot of suggestions here about using other types of communication to transfer the data, that would not be possible in this case, as i need to pass this string to a third party software, which will bring it over on a secure area, where i have access to edit only the javascript, this is why i'm trying to encrypt the text in php and place it inside the website's source, from where the third party software will read it as it is encrypted and will transfer it to the secure section, where i will need to decrypt it back via Javascript (i dont have access to php there).

Comment: Might want to beat the client who set up this process with a wet fish until they agree to implement SSL throughout.

Comment: I don't see you prepending the IV to the ciphertext. Do your libraries do that automatically? If not, that's likely the cause of your issues.

Comment: Do you mean i should have:
`echo base64_encode($iv.$crypttext);` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encrypt in PHP openssl and decrypt in javascript CryptoJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222162/encrypt-in-php-openssl-and-decrypt-in-javascript-cryptojs)

Answer (score 5):

So, after some more digging i came to the following online [encryptor/decryptor](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2011/12/26/online-aes-encryptor-decryptor-javascript/) which led me to the [gibberish-aes at GitHub](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes) repository.

Inside one of the comments on the first link i found that this JS library has a php equivalent, which seems to be working reasonably well and is fairly easy to deploy:
https://github.com/ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php

So thanks to Lars for the answer he provided, i would encourage him to open the repository, i'm sure he'll make someone's life a little bit easier :)

Comment: Thanks, after wasting a lot of time, trying all sorts of libs, your solution helped me!

Answer (score 3):

From the CryptoJS documentation:

> For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and used to derive an actual key and IV. Or you can pass a WordArray that represents the actual key. If you pass the actual key, you must also pass the actual IV.

So in your line

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
```

"oijhd981727783hy18274" is treated as a passphrase to create a key and not as the actual key.

Passing an IV works like this:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f');

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key, { iv: iv });
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had the same problem. I finally got to use SlowAES from http://code.google.com/p/slowaes/ with some fixes and ported it to PHP.

Note: The official sources are broken, just as the official PHP port.

Let me know if you're interested. Then I'd open a new repository at GitHub where you can grab everything you need...

Comment: Thanks Lars, however after i continued digging even after i opened this question and found a working solution ... check the answer below.

Comment: It's above for me, but doesn't matter. It matters to get a nicely solved problem ;) !