# Encrypt in PHP and decrypt in JS - AES256

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

The function will receive a file uploaded, and will encrypt this one to save in the server, i'm think about using openssl_encrypt.

The encryption type will be AES256.

After when a web-service is requested will return a base 64 encrypted document to be decrypted in the JS side using the crypto-js.

For know, my question is how can i do the encryption process using openssl_encrypt php function?

Encrypt process:

1. fopen
2. encrypt
3. encode base64
4. fwrite
5. fclose

Decrypt process:

1. Decode base 64
2. Decrypt
3. Open the pdf document

The processes above, is the idea i have in mind, please correct me if i'm wrong or there is a mistake.

**Phase 1:**

*PHP Code:*

After handling the file:

```
$encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret = "1234567890@@@@@@@@@@123456789012";  //must be 32 char length
$iv = substr($secret, 0, 16);
$encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secret,0,$iv);
```

On jquery to decrypt doesn't work:

```
var ckey = "1234567890@@@@@@@@@@123456789012";
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.content, ckey, { iv: "1234567890@@@@@@" });
```

The pdf is generated again but i'm not able to open, shows an error message "Acrobat cannot open the file"..

Why am i getting this?

Comment: Well, the question has already a vote down, but nobody said why! It's weird!

Comment: It's probably been downvoted because you haven't shown anything that you've attempted. So far you've done some research (which is clear), but you haven't actually tried it. Try first, then ask a question if you have a specific problem.

Comment: My question for know, is if is possible to do AES256 encryption with openssl function and decrypt with cryptojs?

Comment: If they both support AES256, then yes, it's possible (although there's also differences like picking an appropriate cipher, and sharing the key). Effectively, you may be making the system insecure by sharing the key to decrypt the file with the user in javascript, but I don't know your use case.

Comment: The point here is, i want to upload a file(PDF) and encrypt this one! After another system will request a WS where will return the file to be decrypted in JS! So, you advice for this case is to use appropriate cipher? Tks

Comment: Yes, you can encrypt in one and decrypt in the other as seen by this [list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+[cryptojs]+openssl_encrypt). Keep in mind that you need to have TLS enabled for this to be remotely secure: [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Some potentially useful code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507094/issue-encrypting-with-php-openssl-encrypt-then-decrypting-with-js-cryptojs/32517413#32517413

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AES encryption in php and then decryption with Javascript (cryptojs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797238/aes-encryption-in-php-and-then-decryption-with-javascript-cryptojs)

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt/Decrypt working!

PHP SIDE TO ENCRYPT

```
$encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret = "1234567890@@@@@@@@@@123456789012";  //must be 32 char length
$iv = substr($secret, 0, 16);
$encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secret,0,$iv);`
```

CRYPTOJS TO DECRYPT

```
var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data.toString())});
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key), { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv) });
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + btoa(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)));
```

Comment: well! I added the solution to the problem i was asking for, and i got a vote down in my question!! unbelievable how there is people here just to vote and don't even check the whole post!

Comment: This is not very intuitive. What are the "data", "key" and "iv" variables you use in the JavaScript? Please explain.