# encrypt AES 256 with crypto js and decrypt in openssl_decrypt php

Tags: cryptojs

I am tyring to decrypted in php a ecrypted text crytposjs with AES 256 and try all these links:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222162/encrypt-in-php-openssl-and-decrypt-in-javascript-cryptojs/43438494#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222162/encrypt-in-php-openssl-and-decrypt-in-javascript-cryptojs/43438494#_=_)

but none of them works and openssl_decrypt just simply returns false.

could you please help me to find any sample code?

Thanks much for ur help