# how use function pbkdf2 of cryptoJS without nodeJS

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

according to [this link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#from-mnemonic-to-seed), I want to convert mnemonic words to its corresponding seed. I want to do this by **javascript** and use it in **webclients** without **nodeJS**.

the library that I have in mind is [cryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js).

I am planning to use function **pbkdf2**, but I don't know which **js** file I need to add to html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one old answer here how to use cryptoJS:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43438494/2951051

About your last question " which js file I need to add to html page.":

I use this scripts from gitHub: https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS

After that I use this files from `rollups/` folder:

`aes.js` , `pbkdf2.js`, `hmac-sha512.js`

For more random entropy i have changed `random.js` (inside aes.js)  with another random function you can download from : https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico/blob/master/random.js